# Show: If $v \in E^{\perp}$ then it can be written as $v=w+c_1w_1+c_2w_2+\dots +c_kw_k$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

> (i) Assume that $B = \{w_1,\dots,w_k\}$ is an orthogonal basis for $E$. Let $v \in E^{\perp}$ such that $v\neq O_{V}$. Prove that $v=w+c_1w_1+c_2w_2+\dots +c_kw_k$ for some nonzero $w\notin E$ and some $c_1,\dots , c_k \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> (ii) (converse of (i)) Let $B = \{w_1,\dots , w_k\}$ be an orthogonal basis for E. Let $w\notin E$. Prove that $v=w-proj^{(w)}_{w_1}-\dots -proj^{(w)}_{w_k} \in E^{\perp}$

this is how i approached it:

suppose you have an element $v=w+c_1w_1+c_2w_2+\dots +c_kw_k$. For v to belong to $E^\perp$, then v has to be orthogonal to $w_i, \forall i$. hence,

$\langle v,w_i\rangle = \langle w+c_1w_1+c_2w_2+\dots +c_kw_k,w_i\rangle = \langle w,w_i\rangle+\langle c_iw_i,w_i\rangle =\langle w_i,c_iw_i+w\rangle$
Therefore, for $v$ to be in $E^\perp$, $\langle w,w_i\rangle =-c_i\langle w_i,w_i\rangle$. Also, we require w not to be in $E$

I don't know how to move next.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You can choose $w=v$ and $c_k = 0$. The point $v$ cannot be in $E$ since it is non zero.

Comment: I change ${}<v,w_i>{}$ to $\langle v,w_i\rangle$.  That is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to show that any $v \notin E$ can be written as the above with $w \in E^\bot$?

Comment: I posted more branches of the problem.